# The relationship between girth and size in graphs

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I love the exercises 2.1.63 below (on page 78) in the West's textbook *Introduction to Graph Theory*.

**2.1.63.**  Prove that every $n$-vertex graph with $n+1$ edges has girth at most $\lfloor(2 n+2) / 3\rfloor$. For each $n$, construct an example achieving this bound.

I am considering an $n$-vertex graph with $n+k$ edges where $k\leq n$; would there also be a general result?  More generally, if there are $m$ edges ($m\ge 1$), would there be a more general result?

For the second question, the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294505/upper-bound-on-the-number-of-edges-given-number-of-vertices-girth-and-maximum-d) may have something. But if $m$ is not very big, e.g., $m= n+\mathcal{O}(1)$ or $m =\mathcal{O}(n)$ do we have a similar result?